# Mail going to Spam in gmail

Tags: php, joomla

I have a running store, but my emails are going to spam.

I have Joomla 1.7 installed and configured it tu use proper SMTP auth.I have the site running on a shared host.

I have tried to search in email blacklists but it all comes clean.

Am I doing something wrong? Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Look through the hundreds of other questions like that: http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+php%20mail%20going%20to%20spam

Comment: most likely because you didn't configure your spf record http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33786

Comment: Why are you using Joomla 1.7 which is no longer supported? Upgrade to 2.5!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to configure SPF records for the domain, You should contact your host and ask them to configure them..
I had this same problem on my web site. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is complex issue, First of all, you should follow the following tips

1. Tell the people who receive the mails, why they get these mails (at the footer)
2. Give them explicit link to un-subscribe from this list (at the footer)
3. Make the subscribe process double opt-in, so after adding their mail, they should activate through a link sent to their mail

Also Read the following links that may help (You may need help from your server administrator)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_authentication

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail

http://mailchimp.com/about/authentication/

Finally, the best think to avoid your mails getting blocked is to make sure that your users want them .

Answer (score 0):

Joomla 1.7, 2.5 and 3 all feature a mail file which sends the mail without the plaintext alternative, this was killing my sites. I had to add it manually to the core, please see [Joomla mail goes to spam folder: how to add text/plain when sending HTML email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546270/joomla-mail-goes-to-spam-folder-how-to-add-text-plain-when-sending-html-email)