# Intercept all Joomla outgoing emails & reroute them to a specified address

Tags: email, joomla, mailer

I'm working on a new Joomla site and am working on testing outgoing email. I'd like to be able to intercept all outgoing emails and reroute them to an address I specify. It is very useful in development when you have a copy of a live site with thousands of users, so email does not go to real users from the copy site.

It would be great to do this with a extension but have been unable to find one to do some. I'm also open to getting this done on the server side if necessary.

I found a Drupal module that does exactly what I'd like to do except it's obviously for Drupal and note Joomla.

https://drupal.org/project/reroute_email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Joomla-Level you could create a system plugin that loads up own, monkey-patched [`JMail`](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/joomla/mail/mail.php) class.

I'm not sure if you would be able to extend the original `JMail` because of namespace conflict, so maybe you'd have copy it over and alter the `addRecipient` method:

```
public function addRecipient($recipient, $name = '')
{
    $this->add('custom@email.com', 'custom name', 'AddAddress');

    return $this;
}
```

References:

- Related Stack Overflow answer: [How to override core classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546270/joomla-mail-goes-to-spam-folder-how-to-add-text-plain-when-sending-html-email)
- Gist: [plgSystemOverrides](https://gist.github.com/dongilbert/3237387)

Comment: I don't think the addRecipient method is always used to send email. e.g. JFactory::getMailer()->sendMail($from, $sender, $email, $subject, $body)

Comment: Nevermind, the sendMail method uses addRecipient. To test I just modified the mail.php on my staging site. If I ever get around to creating a plugin I'll post it here. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend creating a override plugin for the Mail package, otherwise there's a chance your changes will be overwritten with Joomla update (like updating the docblocks copyright to 2014).